# sending email using spring framework get error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Following is the my code to sending the email.

```
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;

public class TestArrayList {
    private MailSender mailSender;
    public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String msg) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(from);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(msg);
        mailSender.send(message);   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestArrayList obj=new TestArrayList();
        obj.sendMail("from@no-spam.com", "to@no-spam.com",  "Testing123", "Testing only \n\n Hello Spring Email Sender");

        }

}
```

But i got the following error message I don't get it where I m wrong.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestArrayList.sendMail(TestArrayList.java:16)
    at TestArrayList.main(TestArrayList.java:20)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mailSender.send(message);
```

Here `mailSender` is `null` as it is not initialized.
Initialize it

```
private MailSender mailSender = new MailSender();
```

or use Spring annotation to inject it.

Comment: when u tried to initialize mailSender it give Cannot instantiate the type MailSender error message...

Comment: @vijayk: Add more details from stacktrace so that we can identify the exact problem.

Comment: I m just initiate the mailSender object but it give error when u just type at that time it give error..

Comment: @vijayk: I guess `MailSender` is a interface you need to use a implementation of that.